# How to authenticate with Google App Engine Admin API from a Google Cloud Function context

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to turn a Google App Engine Flex environment off when not in use, using a Google Cloud Function. I am struggling to find the best way to authenticate using the nodejs GoogleAPIs client.

Surely I don't need user input?

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of hunting to discover the bundled GoogleAuth library actually picks up the permissions of the Cloud Function environment if you specify the required OAuth scopes. The great thing about this approach is there are no keys to manage!

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const gae = google.appengine('v1');

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only']
});

async function trigger(event, context) {
    const authClient = await auth.getClient();
    const versionsResponse = await gae.apps.services.versions.list({
        auth: authClient,
        appsId: "<APP_ID>",
        servicesId: "<SERVICE_ID>",
        fields: "versions(id,name,servingStatus)"
    });
    // Rest of code ...   
}
```

I found the code [here](https://corepox.net/devlog/reduce-google-app-engine-flex-costs-with-cloud-scheduler-cloud-functions-and-the-gae-admin-api)

Comment: Have a look to Cloud Run. The code package deployed on AppEngine Flex and Cloud Run are very close (both package in container), and the security policy is the same as function (your work can be reuse). Anyway, thanks for sharing your discovery !